# Setup whisper for callee - So when I answer, I know where the call is coming from

Tags: twilio

I am sorry. I am a new to this so forgive me in advance. I'm searching for an answer and I was not able to understand when searching previous inquiries.

I am starting a TwiML Bin and so far my code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Say>This call is being recorded for quality assurance purposes</Say> . 
<Dial record="true">+1 858-220-8650</Dial>
</Response>
```

When I receive the forwarded phone call, and I answer it, I want a message to say "phone call from website xyz" and then connect the call.

Is this possible from just within the TwiML Bin? Or do I have to utilize some external code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with TwiML Bins, you will need to use the [URL attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url) on the Number noun to "chain" them together.

First create your whisper bin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>phone call from website xyz</Say>
</Response>
```

Then use this with the URL attribute on your existing bin, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>This call is being recorded for quality assurance purposes</Say> 
  <Dial record="true">
    <Number url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
      18582208650
    </Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

When the call is answered it will say the message from the whisper bin immediately before connecting the calls. Hope this helps! :)